# Does relativity in any way "disprove" Newton?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, relativity

I was reading a science magazine and it claimed that [Einstein's theory of relativity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_of_relativity) disproves all of Newtonian physics. I was highly skeptical because all we have been learning at school is Newtonian physics and we haven't even touched on relativity yet. Does that mean that the school is teaching me things that in reality are not true?

Additionally, by "all of Newtonian physics" does that include Newton's 3 laws of motion? Gravity?

The magazine also mentioned that quantum physics is also somehow disproving these previously held "theories".

Support would be appreciated.

Comment: I think A. Einstein is not out to discredit his favorite hero however he finds them (Sir Issac Newton's work on laws of motion) rather unsatisfying so set out on an incredible journey to unravel the mystery of the universe and that just my ungrounded opinion lol. by the way your internet works is thank to Newton who help sending satellite into low earth orbit in the first place be grateful.

Comment: No it does not - you should probably unsubscribe from whatever magazine you're reading. Relativity supersedes Newtonian mechanics, but Newtonian mechanics is still found at a low-energy approximation of Relativity.